# Would using features of newer version of Google Play Services crash the app, if user has older version of the Google Play Services?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I want to use new Face Detection feature of Google Play Services, it has introduced in 7.8 version. I want to know if I release my app, would it work on phones with older version of Google Play Services, if not would it crash or?

Comment: I think the best way would be to test this in an experiment yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions in the [GoogleApiAvailability](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GoogleApiAvailability) class.

> Helper class for verifying that the Google Play services APK is
>   available and up-to-date on this device

Use the `isGooglePlayServicesAvailable` method.

> public int isGooglePlayServicesAvailable (Context context)
>
> Verifies that Google Play services is installed and enabled on this
>   device, and that the version installed on this device is no older than
>   the one required by this client.

The `isUserResolvableError` and `getErrorDialog` methods can then be used to install the latest version from Play Store if required.

Answer (score 0):

It would indeed crash on an older phone since there will be methods in the newer version not in the older one. Just make sure you have an exception for handling an older version - or alternatively set the minimum required version of Android for your application higher.